# I am having issue with React router v6 while using Elements of stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, react-router-dom

> Uncaught Error: [Elements] is not a `<Route>` component. All component
> children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

I even tried to use `Fragment`

I am also using the protected route.

```
    const App = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState();

  async function getStripeApiKey() {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/stripeapikey");
    setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Roboto", "Droid Sans", "Chilanka"],
      },
    });
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
    getStripeApiKey();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} exact />
         
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} exact />
  
            {/* {stripeApiKey && (
              <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
                <Route exact path="/process/payment" element={<Payment />} />
              </Elements>
            )} */}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} exact />
          <Route
            path="/password/reset/:token"
            element={<ResetPassword />}
            exact
          />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} exact />
        </Routes>

        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to include all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? See [mcve]. Basically we need to see from the `Routes` component down to what you are trying to render on a route.

Comment: hey @DrewReese thanks for your consideration 
I have edited the code and pasted the code of App.js
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is this `Elements` component? Where is that declared or imported from?

Comment: Elements is the component of stripe and it is imported from the stripe library
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component can only be rendered by the `Routes` component, or in the case of nested routes, another `Route` component. The `Elements` component is neither of these so it can't be rendered directly by a `Route` or `Routes` component. It appears that `Elements` is some sort of Stripe "context provider".

## Solution

The solution here is to either wrap `Payment` directly with the `Elements` component, or render it in a layout route that renders an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their `element` content into.

### Wrapper Example

Using a wrapper component is useful if you only need to wrap a single routed component.

```
{stripeApiKey && (
  <Route
    path="/process/payment"
    element={(
      <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
        <Payment />
      </Elements>
    )}
  />
)}
```

### Layout Example

Layout routes are useful if you need to wrap several routes.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ElementsLayout = ({ stripe }) => (
  <Elements stripe={stripe}>
    <Outlet />
  </Elements>
);

export default ElementsLayout;
```

...

```
import ElementsLayout from '../path/to/ElementsLayout';

const App = () => {
  ...

  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState();

  ...

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
            {stripeApiKey && (
              <Route
                element={<ElementsLayout stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)} />}
              >
                <Route path="/process/payment" element={<Payment />} />
              </Route>
            )}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route
            path="/password/reset/:token"
            element={<ResetPassword />}
          />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```